# Add % to the barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Im trying to add the percentage to each bar:

```
# Set up the work directory in which all data is gonna be extracted
H1517 = read.csv("HiBAPMapGraph.csv") #Change name of the file
library(ggplot2)

# Histogram on a Categorical variable
p <- ggplot(H1517, aes(Chromosome)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Genome), width = 
0.5) + scale_fill_manual("Genome", values = c("A" = "chartreuse3", "B" = 
"darkorange1 ", "D" = "gold1"))  
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6, face="bold", size=12), 
axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=10)) 
p.labs <- p + labs(x = "Chromosome", y = "# markers")
red.bold.italic.text <- element_text(face = "bold", size = 10)
p.labs + theme(title = red.bold.italic.text, axis.title = 
red.bold.italic.text) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1)) +  
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1800,200) + geom_text(aes(label = 
paste0(ValueG*100,"%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2)
```

But the next message comes:

```
List of 2
 $ axis.text.x:List of 11
  ..$ family       : NULL
  ..$ face         : chr "bold"
  ..$ colour       : NULL
  ..$ size         : num 12
  ..$ hjust        : NULL
  ..$ vjust        : num 0.6
  ..$ angle        : num 65
  ..$ lineheight   : NULL
  ..$ margin       : NULL
  ..$ debug        : NULL
  ..$ inherit.blank: logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"
 $ axis.text.y:List of 11
  ..$ family       : NULL
  ..$ face         : chr "bold"
  ..$ colour       : NULL
  ..$ size         : num 10
  ..$ hjust        : NULL
  ..$ vjust        : NULL
  ..$ angle        : NULL
  ..$ lineheight   : NULL
  ..$ margin       : NULL
  ..$ debug        : NULL
  ..$ inherit.blank: logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "theme" "gg"
 - attr(*, "complete")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "validate")= logi TRUE
```

And I dont get my graph! :( any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Here is some data:

```
    Chromosome  Genome  ValueG  ValueChr
AX-94493709 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94913549 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94856564 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-95182909 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94667633 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94944833 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94793453 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95079458 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95072382 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
```

In advance, thank you!

Comment: is the chromosome column made of `1`s or does it include the whole AX-something?

Comment: The 1 is part of the data (another column)

Comment: so please edit the question so your data has 5 columns

Comment: your lack of code styling is heavily contributing to your confusion and — amongst other things — you're missing a `)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr and a `+` sign before `theme`

Comment: And then some. If the question was not related to positioning text labels it should have been (and likely still should be) closed as a "typo", especially since it's not reproducible in current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate the "code styling" comment:

```
# perhaps have all library() calls up front
library(ggplot2)

# perhaps keep consistent assignment operators
H1517 <- read.table(text = "Chromosome  Genome  ValueG  ValueChr
AX-94493709 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94913549 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94856564 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-95182909 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94667633 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94944833 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94793453 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95079458 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95072382 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
")

# Some concept of formatting would have made the original block readable
p <- ggplot(H1517, aes(Chromosome)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Genome), width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Genome",
    values = c(
      "A" = "chartreuse3", "B" = "darkorange1 ", "D" = "gold1"
    )
  )

# why is this dangling?
theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.6, face = "bold", size = 12),
  axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10)
)

p.labs <- p + labs(x = "Chromosome", y = "# markers")

red.bold.italic.text <- element_text(face = "bold", size = 10)

# Formatting this in some basic way wld have likely enabled you to discover the missing `)`
p.labs + theme(
  title = red.bold.italic.text,
  axis.title = red.bold.italic.text
) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1800, 200)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(ValueG * 100, "%")),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2
  )
```

So ^^ is still broken but *kinda* readable (it's still a hodge podge of copypasta).

Let's transform it:

```
library(ggplot2)

H1517 <- read.table(text = "Chromosome  Genome  ValueG  ValueChr
AX-94493709 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94913549 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-94856564 1   A   0.047264487 0.179561886
AX-95182909 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94667633 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94944833 1   B   0.098197907 0.179561886
AX-94793453 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95079458 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
AX-95072382 1   D   0.034099493 0.179561886
")

red.bold.italic.text <- element_text(face = "bold", size = 10)

ggplot(H1517, aes(x=Chromosome)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Genome), width = 0.5) +
  # geom_text(
  #   aes(label = paste0(ValueG * 100, "%")),
  #   position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2
  # ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1800, 200)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Genome",
    values = c(
      "A" = "chartreuse3", "B" = "darkorange1 ", "D" = "gold1"
    )
  ) +
  labs(x = "Chromosome", y = "# markers") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.6, face = "bold", size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10),
    title = red.bold.italic.text,
    axis.title = red.bold.italic.text
  )
```

[image]

NOTE: We've commented out the `geom_text()` because it's broken.

So, is the above image what you're looking for sans labels?

If so, how is `ggplot2` supposed to know what to do with `ValueG` here?:

```
geom_text(
  aes(label = paste0(ValueG * 100, "%")),
  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2
)
```

`geom_text` has a default `stat` of `identity`. `geom_bar`'s default is `count`. Even if you fixed that, How is `ValueG` supposed to get summarised for the three groups? And, where do you want the labels if this is the right graph output? Tops? Centered?

I highly encourage you to restructure your source code and then compute the necessary values and groups outside of ggplot2 and use `geom_col` vs `geom_bar`.